# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'sinon.spy()')

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sinon

I'm trying to use [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) in testing of a backbone application. But unfortunately I cannot use spy method due to error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'sinon.spy()')
```

Here is the steps to reproduce the error:

1. Create an empty project with [backbone yeoman generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone)
2. Install sinon: `cd test && bower install sinon`
3. Include in test/index.html `<script src="bower_components/sinon/lib/sinon.js"></script>`
4. Create spy in test/spec/test.js:

   ```
   describe('Give it some context', function () {
       describe('maybe a bit more context here', function () {
           it('should run here few assertions', function () {
             var spy = sinon.spy();
             spy.should.be.ok;
           });
       });
   });
   ```
5. Run the test with grunt: `grunt test`
6. The test will fail with a described error.

Could anyone help to find out what is wrong?

Comment: What is content of `bower_components/sinon/lib` directory? `sinon.js`, `sinon-1.7.3.js` or something else?

Comment: See if this can help you [Stubs fail in browser environment since sinon 1.7 release](https://github.com/busterjs/buster/issues/354)

Comment: sinon.js file and lib folder which contains spy.js, stub.js, etc. It seems that sinon.js should include dependencies from lib folder, but it doesn't.

Comment: The github issue is relevant only for 1.7.0 version. And my issue can be reproduced with 1.6.0 and 1.7.3 as well. And actually I do not think the issue correlates with mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that such functionality as spies, stubs, etc should be added manually by including scripts from `lib/sinon` folder. This fact is mentioned in Installation section. And due to the code of the core sinon.js file only in Node.js environment it is done automatically.

Comment: What sort of syntax would you use for this? See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333595/pulling-in-sinon-submodules-in-browser-with-amd-and-webpack)

Answer (score 14):

I'll just leave here the list of files that `sinon` conveniently forgets to load if it is loaded as a `<script>` or with `require.js` (as AMD module) - basically anything else than in `node.js`:

```
"sinon/lib/sinon.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/call.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/behavior.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/mock.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/collection.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/sandbox.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/test.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/test_case.js",
"sinon/lib/sinon/match.js"
```

Feel free to skip any of those but expect sinon to fail in curious ways.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with sinon 1.17.2 and Chrome 47.0. After trying the above solutions and variations of those, I ended up using the nuclear option and switching to [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/).

For my test suite, it only took about 15 minutes of some global find-and-replace to convert my chai 'expects' into Jasmine ones and some differences around mocha before syntax; Jasmine flagged the unexpected syntax clearly. [Jasmine spy objects](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpyObj%3C/code%3E) were a fine substitute for sinon.

Comment: Good call, this worked for me as well. No idea what the problem is with this version of sinon.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other answers, I didn't install simon manually by including each individual source file. Instead I followed the advice of [How To Install Sinon.JS In The Browser With Bower](http://jaspervalero.com/install-sinon-js-browser-bower/).

```
bower install http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.17.6.js
```

then

```
bower list -p 
 'sinon-1.17.6': 'bower_components/sinon-1.17.6/index.js'
```

And

```
 <script src="bower_components/sinon-1.17.6/index.js"></script>
```

Worked for me.