# Pulling in sinon submodules in browser with AMD and webpack

Tags: javascript, amd, sinon, webpack

I'm running into the same problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570301/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-sinon-spy). Basically sinon only pulls in all required submodules if you're using node. If you try to use it in the browser with AMD (I'm using webpack) apparently you have to manually include `lib/spy.js`.

I have a webpack module that currently exports sinon:

```
exports.sinon = require('sinon');
```

How would I modify that to roll in `spy.js`?

I think this is more of a CommonJS syntax question than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
exports.sinon = require("sinon");
exports.sinon.spy = require("sinon/lib/sinon/spy");
exports.sinon.spyCall = require("sinon/lib/sinon/call");
exports.sinon.behavior = require("sinon/lib/sinon/behavior");
exports.sinon.stub = require("sinon/lib/sinon/stub");
exports.sinon.mock = require("sinon/lib/sinon/mock");
exports.sinon.collection = require("sinon/lib/sinon/collection");
exports.sinon.assert = require("sinon/lib/sinon/assert");
exports.sinon.sandbox = require("sinon/lib/sinon/sandbox");
exports.sinon.test = require("sinon/lib/sinon/test");
exports.sinon.testCase = require("sinon/lib/sinon/test_case");
exports.sinon.match = require("sinon/lib/sinon/match");
```

This is basically mimicking the behavior in sinon.js. If anyone has a better/cleaner solution please post it and I'll accept. And now that I look at it I wonder why there're

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to use the `spy` function? I'm using enzyme with mocha for a test suite